# How to extract some part of a string?

Tags: c#

I have a string = "C:\Users\Desktop\bin\data\so on"

I want to extract just the "C:\Users\Desktop\" part.. 
what is the easiest way to get the result ?

Comment: based on what logic? Please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = @"C:\Users\Desktop\bin\data\so on";
string result = String.Join("\\",s.Split('\\').Take(3));
```

**Result**
C:\Users\Desktop

Comment: one more thing how can done the same task by checking in the string to break string whenever string founds \bin ? and it can cut all the string after /bin and result will again the same i.e "Result C:\Users\Desktop"

Comment: you may try s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf(@"\bin"));

Answer (score 1):

Take in to account that there're *two* possible *directory separators* (your input looks like a path):

```
  String s = "C:\Users\Desktop\bin\data\so on";

  String result = String.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), 
                              s.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
                                      Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar).Take(3));
```

Or if you want to keep on until `"/bin"` or `"\bin"` is found you should change `Take` to `TakeWhile`:

```
  String result = String.Join(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), 
                          s.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
                                  Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar).TakeWhile(
                                    x => !String.Equals(x, "bin", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Naive soultion as `Substring(@"\bin")` can be *dangerous* on inputs like that `"C:\Windows\MyBins\Bin\SomeStaff"`

Comment: how can done the same task by checking in the string to break string whenever string founds \bin ? and it can cut all the string after /bin and result will again the same i.e "Result C:\Users\Desktop"

Comment: @user3418729: Just change "Take" to "TakeWhile"